# Evaluation relation In Pierce's book: meaning of "a relation satisfies a rule if ..."

Tags: types, programming-languages

Pierce writes in his [book](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) in Def. 3.5.2 :

> A rule is satisfied by a relation if, for each instance of the rule,
>   either the conclusion is in the relation or one of the premises is
>   not.

So this means if a relation ( which is a set of term pairs, where the pairs are denoted as t->t' ) contains the element `true->false` then that relation also satisfies the rules given in Fig. 3-1 because Def 3.5.2 does not forbid the presence of such elements in the relation which are not an instance of a conclusion of a rule.

So, in other words, the element `true->false` is not an instance of the conclusion of E-IF, so the definition 3.5.2 does not tell anything about whether `true->false` can be in a relation satisfying the rules in Fig 3-1 or not. Def 3.5.2 only talks about relation elements which have the form `" if .... then .... -> .... "`, but does not explicitly forbid ( or actually say anything about ) the presence of the element `true->false`, for example.

**Question** : is this understanding of mine correct ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is rather too theoretical for the likes of us sweat-stained, furrow-browed, hackers.  Try the soft-skinned, sweet-smelling ivory-tower dwellers at http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmmm.... well I don't think its too mathematical for this community, after all, this is undergrad (BSc) curriculum material. Understanding Pierce's book is pretty much a must for any self-respecting coder IMHO. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: I, for one, happen to *like* this question. Did you ever find an answer to it?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I think HPFMark was correct in saying that SOF won't give an answer... might be good to move this question to CS. - I just don't know how to move it. Btw, I might have found an answer, but after 2 years I got out of the topic so much that I forgot practically everything, it would take my a day to refresh my mind and understand the question itself again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. A relation can satisfy the rules while also containing pairs that are not justified by the rules.

For example, if `R` is the evaluation relation presented in the text, which satisfies all of the rules in Fig. 3-1, then the relation `R` plus your pair `true -> false` *also* satisfies all of the rules. This makes sense since any relation must satisfy each rule in isolation; if we didn't allow additional pairs, then the relation `{ if true then true else false -> true, if false then true else false -> false }` would *not* satisfy E-IfTrue in isolation since the second element cannot be justified by E-IfTrue. If the relation cannot satisfy that single rule in isolation, then it cannot satisfy all three of the rules presented. For this reason, additional "unjustifiable" pairs are allowed when satisfying an inference rule.

That being said, the very next definition, 3.5.3, explicitly *omits* pairs like `true -> false` from the particular relation being discussed by specifying that it is the *smallest* relation satisfying all three rules. While we *could* discuss a larger relation, this restriction means that, in Pierce's words, "a statement `t -> t'` is derivable iff it is justifiable by the rules."